# Are there any websites that allow you to perform GET requests using there API?

Tags: get, request

I'm working on a project where I need to perform a GET request to a domain. It won't work purely in Javascript because the site is cross-origin. Is there a service that when called can return the contents of a page?

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://httpbin.org/) one :) specifically this endpoint over [here](https://httpbin.org/get)

/get Returns GET data.

it will reply every time you call it with a response like this

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    // all the headers will be here
  }, 
  "origin": "<YOUR IP WILL BE HERE>", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

JSON format that you can consume and view to your client/end